# How to compute MIN$(A(x), B(x))$

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

I have two polynomials: $\;A(x) = \sum a_i\;x^i$, $\quad B(x) = \sum b_i\;x^i$.
Given $A(x)$, $B(x)$, I want to compute $\;C(x) = $MIN$(A(x), B(x)) = c_i\;x^i$ where $c_i = $MIN$(a_i, b_i)$.

How can I do it automatically in *Mathematica*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another one, possibly shorter, which works with any number of unequal degree polys:

```
f[p_, x_] := FromDigits[Min @@@ Reverse@Transpose@PadRight@CoefficientList[p, x], x]

Expand@f[{6 - 5 x +   x^2 + 2 x^3 + 4 x^4 + 4 x^5 - 2 x^6, 
         -4 + 7 x - 3 x^2 - 3 x^3 + 5 x^4}               , x]
```

> -4 - 5 x - 3 x^2 - 3 x^3 + 4 x^4 - 2 x^6

Works for any number of polys:

```
Expand@f[{6 - 5 x +   x^2 + 2 x^3 + 4 x^4 + 4 x^5 - 2 x^6, 
         -4 + 7 x - 3 x^2 - 3 x^3 + 5 x^4, 
        -11 -11 x}                                       , x]
```

> -11 - 11 x - 3 x^2 - 3 x^3 - 2 x^6

Comment: Thanks to @ssch :) http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11805319#11805319

Answer (score 7):

With exact coefficient lists you can do the following:

```
a = {1, 3, 5};
b = {3, 2, 4};
c = MapThread[Min, {a, b}]
```

> ```
>  {1, 2, 4}
> ```

With polynimials:

```
pa = 1 + 3 x + 5 x^2;
pb = 3 + 2 x + 3 x^2;

Plus @@ MapIndexed[Min[#1] x^(First[#2] - 1) &, Transpose@CoefficientList[{pa, pb}, x]]
```

> ```
> 1 + 2 x + 4 x^2
> ```

*Update:* generalization to any number of nonaligned polynomials (inspired by ubpdqn)

```
f[p_, x_] := FromCoefficientRules[#[[1, 1]] -> Min@PadRight[#[[All, 2]], Length[p]] & /@ 
     GatherBy[Join @@ CoefficientRules[p, x], First], x]

f[{6 - 5 x + x^2 + 2 x^3 + 4 x^4 + 4 x^5 - 2 x^6, -4 + 7 x - 3 x^2 - 3 x^3 + 5 x^4}, x]
```

> ```
> -4 - 5 x - 3 x^2 - 3 x^3 + 2 x^4 - 2 x^6
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Here is the way to work with any number of polynomials of different orders:

```
minPoly[polys_List, var_] := With[{rg = Range[0, Max @ Exponent[polys, var]]}, 
                                  Min @ Coefficient[ polys, var, #]& /@ rg.var^rg]
```

Let's choose a list of polynomials, e.g.

```
{a1, a2, a3} = {10        - 2 x^2 - 8 x^3 +   x^4 - 4 x^5 + 3 x^6,
                -8 +  2 x - 2 x^2 + 2 x^3 +   x^4 + 2 x^5 + 9 x^6 - 4 x^7,
                -8 + 10 x + 2 x^2 -   x^3 - 4 x^4 - 4 x^5 - 2 x^6 +   x^7 - 10 x^8};
```

then we have

```
minPoly[{a1, a2, a3}, x]
```

> ```
> -8 - 2 x^2 - 8 x^3 - 4 x^4 - 4 x^5 - 2 x^6 - 4 x^7 - 10 x^8
> ```

If we know that orders of the polynomials are equal, for example:

```
A[x_]:= -4 - x + 2 x^2 - x^3 + 4 x^4 + x^5
B[x_]:= 10 + 5 x^2 - 3 x^3 - 7 x^4 - 2 x^5
```

this is another approach:

```
x^Range[0, 5].MapThread[ Min, CoefficientList[{A[x], B[x]}, x]]
```

> ```
> -4 - x + 2 x^2 - 3 x^3 - 7 x^4 - 2 x^5
> ```

of course `minPoly` works nicely as well:

```
minPoly[{A[x], B[x]}, x]
```

> ```
> -4 - x + 2 x^2 - 3 x^3 - 7 x^4 - 2 x^5
> ```

Answer (score 3):

On the off chance that the polynomials have unequal highest degree (hence unequal coefficient list lengths):

```
func[u_, v_, x_] := Module[{cl, ncl},
  cl = GatherBy[
     Join @@ (CoefficientRules[#] & /@ {u, v}), #[[1]] &] /. {{a_} -> 
       b_} :> {{a} -> b, {a} -> 0};
  ncl = First /@ (SortBy[#, #[[2]] &] & /@ cl);
  Total[(#[[2]] x^First@#[[1]]) & /@ ncl]
  ]
```

Testing:

```
 6 - 5 x + x^2 + 2 x^3 + 4 x^4 + 4 x^5 - 2 x^6
-4 + 7 x - 3 x^2 - 3 x^3 + 5 x^4
```

then

```
func[6 - 5 x + x^2 + 2 x^3 + 4 x^4 + 4 x^5 - 2 x^6,
 -4 + 7 x - 3 x^2 - 3 x^3 + 5 x^4, x]
```

yields:

```
-4 - 5 x - 3 x^2 - 3 x^3 + 4 x^4 - 2 x^6
```